# MVC CheckboxFor never passing view correct value? Binding checkboxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a MVC project im currently working on and i have a check box in one of my views. When i change the check box it never passes the correct value to my modal?

View CheckboxFor:

```
  @model OBASA.Models.EmployeeModal

  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
    <legend>EmployeeModel</legend>


     <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active)
     </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active)
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active)
     </div>
     <p>
         <input type="submit" name="Sub" value="Save" />
     </p>
    </fieldset>
    }
```

Modal:

```
public class EmployeeModal
{
   public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

In run time when i check or un check the check box it never passes the value, its always false.

Please can someone tell me how to bind this correctly for MVC.

Comment: Where is your form tag which posts the values to your controller?

Comment: Maybe because it's `false` by default and you didn't implement saving it yet?

Comment: @Steve I the view contains many other field's witch i can save just fine. its only the checkboxfor i'm struggling to bind

Comment: If you inspeect your HTTP what do you see? I'm thinking you may have multiple Active(s) returned in the form?

Comment: Can you add your controller action (at least the signature). I created a view and controller exactly like yours and Active is set to true when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: it's amazing that 6 years later MVC still has a bug with this. I answered the question with workarounds for VS 2017 below.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is correct, though you have not posted your controller code. It needs to look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Junk()
{
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Junk(EmployeeModal model)
{
  bool bActive = model.Active;
  return View(model);
}
```